# Cannot convert buffer[200] to str[]

Tags: c++

I have to read some text from console and then search for the text "simple" in that string. I have:

```
char Buffer[200];
cin >> Buffer; //read text form keybord

char str[] = Buffer;
char * pch;
pch = strstr (str,"simple");
strncpy (pch,"sample",6);
puts (str);
```

How to convert `Buffer[200]` to `str[]` so that the program works.

Comment: Use `std::string`. Really.

Comment: Would help if we had the declaration of Buffer.

Comment: And if you can't (and here I mean by order from up high) use `std::string`, why not use `Buffer` directly in the `strstr` call? Also, if you really want to go on using arrays and pointer (not recommended) then you should read more about pointers and their relationship with arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you insist on using C-style strings, you'd probably want something like:

```
char Buffer[200];
cin >> Buffer; //read text form keybord

char *pos = strstr(buffer, "simple");
if (pos) {
    buffer[1] = 'a';
    puts(buffer);
}
```

If you want to write actual C++, you'd probably do something more like:

```
std::string buffer;

std::getline(std::cin, buffer);

int pos;

if ((pos=buffer.find("simple")) !=std::string::npos)
    buffer[pos+1] = 'a';

std::cout << buffer;
```